# Array declaration problem in C with variables

Tags: c

Is this allowed in C Language as given below:

```
int a=2, b=3;
int arr[a+b];
```

Is this a valid C statement?

Comment: This isn't a declaration, just a normal array subscript expression.

Comment: Do you mean `int a=2,b=3; int arr[a+b];`?

Comment: It's only valid if `arr` is a pointer or array object declared.. somewhere. And even then, it's pointless as it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: @Aman Sharma, you cant declare an array with local variable! The max you can do is create constats and do something like this:

`#define A = 2
#define B = 3

int arr[A+B];`

Comment: Eric Postpischil - yes that's the statement.

Comment: You can easily check yourself: does `echo 'int main() { int a=2, b=3; int arr[a+b]; arr[0] = 0; return arr[0]; }' | gcc -x c -W -Wall -o /dev/null -` report errors or warnings? (the assignment and return are needed because otherwise the declarations would be useless and superfluous, thus generating a warning)

Comment: @sourabmaity: That statement is not completely correct. As already stated in the answer, [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are specified in the latest ISO C standard an optional feature. So your statement is only correct for implementations (i.e. compilers) that do not implement this optional feature.

Comment: @LSerni: Testing like that shows only what one specific compiler does in one specific circumstance. It does not definitively reveal what the C standard says. Such a test could pass because a compiler supports an extension not defined by the C standard, and an assignment and print could appear to work even if their behavior were undefined by the C standard. So recommending such testing is not a good way to answer questions like this.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you are, of course, correct. At the same time, GCC *tries* to adhere to *some* standards ( https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html ), so I feel that checking that way ought to give some kind of indication. At the very least, compilation succeeding would hint that *some* standards allow whatever one is attempting. The fact that it is just a heuristic, not by far a definitive test, is why I neither suggested this as an answer nor downvoted the question (much as I would have like to read "These compilers I have tried behave thusly...")

Answer (score 3):

An array declare with a size that is not a *integer constant expression* is called a [*variable length array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). It is allowed in C, although not for arrays with static or thread storage duration.

The 1999 C standard required C implementations to support variable length arrays. The 2011 standard made support optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define A 2
#define B 3

int main(){
   
  int a=A, b=B, arra[A+B];

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @4386427 No but, thats the best option! I will edit it